# Combining multiple For Do While loops for efficiency vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am have a macro that takes out junk sales based on item # (column A). As you can see by the code below, there are a lot of junk (lines that need to be deleted) item numbers that start with the "40-xxxxx". I want to combine these loops so that the macro will delete ALL item #'s that start with "40-xxxxx" **EXCEPT** "40-00017" & "40-00004".

```
    sItem = Cells(I, 1)

    Do While Left(sItem, 8) = "40-00087" 'labor-annual refinish
        Rows(I).Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
        sItem = Cells(I, 1)
    Loop
Next I

For I = 2 To nRowMax
    sItem = Cells(I, 1)

    Do While Left(sItem, 8) = "40-00076" 'CONNOISSEURS CLOTH
        Rows(I).Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
        sItem = Cells(I, 1)
    Loop
Next I

For I = 2 To nRowMax
    sItem = Cells(I, 1)

    Do While Left(sItem, 8) = "40-00007" 'labor jewelery
        Rows(I).Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
        sItem = Cells(I, 1)
    Loop
Next I

For I = 2 To nRowMax
    sItem = Cells(I, 1)

    Do While Left(sItem, 8) = "40-00073" 'foam cleaner blitz
        Rows(I).Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
        sItem = Cells(I, 1)
    Loop
Next I

For I = 2 To nRowMax
    sItem = Cells(I, 1)

    Do While Left(sItem, 8) = "40-00084" 'labor-razny 1st
        Rows(I).Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
        sItem = Cells(I, 1)
    Loop
Next I

For I = 2 To nRowMax
    sItem = Cells(I, 5)

    Do While Left(sItem, 2) = "GC" 'gift cards
        Rows(I).Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
        sItem = Cells(I, 5)
    Loop
Next I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Easier to loop backwards when deleting rows rather than resetting the cell

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, nRowMax As Long

For i = nRowMax To 2 Step -1
    If Left(Cells(i, 1), 6) = "40-000" Then
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "40-00017" And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "40-00004" Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have to say though, go with @Coffeegrinder's approach (as long as you don't have any blank rows).

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter instead. You can use macro recorder as well for this. Much simpler and a lot quicker.